# How to call object property in another key before execution

Tags: javascript, object

I want to call `name` property in another key. Is it possible? If yes, then how can we achieve this?

```
let user = {
        name: "John",
        age: this.name,  
      };
      console.warn(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? 
What is it you are trying to achieve?

```js
let userA = {
        name: "John",
        age: 8 
      };
      
let user = {
        name: "John",
        age: userA.name 
      };
console.log(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not in a position to test it at the moment, but I think, in theory, this should work:

```
let user = { 
  name: "John" 
}; 
user.age = user.name
console.log(user.age);
// output: John
```

Comment: No. its not working. user.age is undefined

Comment: @anil Edited for another possible solution.